# Fire event when inner html in div changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have `div` for some informations, which are filled into with `.innerHTML` by clicking on the button. The goal is I want to `.slideDown` the div when the text in div is added. Is it possible to do it with jQuery ?

Example:

```
<div id="calcInfo"></div>
```

Adding text into div -

```
document.getElementById("calcInfo").innerHTML = 'someText';
```

I want to use this function after it :)

```
if ($('#calcInfo').text().trim().length > 0) {
   $('#calcInfo').slideDown('slow', function() {});
};
```

I was trying `.change()` function, but it only works for `input` and `textarea` elements. Many thanks for answer !

Ondrej

Comment: Could you not bind this code to the button's click function if checking for content change isn't working?

Comment: No, because this div contains infos about calculation on the web and sometimes contains it and sometimes no.

Comment: I am using `.setInterval()` for now, but this is not good solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it by extending the $.html function. Like this:

```
(function($)
{
    var oldHtml = $.fn.html;
    $.fn.html = function()
    {
        var ret = oldHtml.apply(this, arguments);

        //trigger your event.
        this.trigger("change");

        return ret;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Attach event handler:

```
$("#calcInfo").on("change",function(){
     if ($(this).text().trim().length > 0) {
        $(this).slideDown('slow', function() {});
     };
});
```

When you need to change your html. Do it like this:

```
$("#calcInfo").html('someText');
```

Comment: Hey, it's super cool :) I didn't know anything about changing jQuery functions. Thanks you very much ! ! !