# How can I automatically call a function on load in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to automatically get the content in `#mydiv` when I load a page. Since the content is dynamically, so I just use `.on()`. It works when I click the `#mydiv`.

But can it work without clicking the `#mydiv`? It will be nice if it loads automatically.

```
$( "#mydiv" ).on( "click", function() {
  alert( $( this ).text() );
});
```

I have tried "load", but didn't get any luck...

Comment: Load automatically means?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery events .load(), .ready(), .unload()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683072/jquery-events-load-ready-unload)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to do this *specifically* with jQuery? Browsers already has means to call some JavaScript code on page load:

```
<body onload="alert($('#mydiv').text())">
```

Or,

```
<body onload="alert(document.getElementById('mydiv').innerText)">
```

Above two will do the same.

Any code you specify between a `<script>` tag will get executed just when the script tag is loaded.

```
<script>alert($('#mydiv').text());</script>
```

And if you want to call a function when `innerHTML` of an element is changed, you should take a look at these questions:

- [Fire event when inner html in div changed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17908002/1461424)
- [Listen to changes within a DIV and act accordingly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2712124/1461424)
- [jQuery watch for domElement changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1960919/1461424)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
$(function(){
  alert($( "#mydiv" ).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv" > Some Text </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

do you mean this?

```
$(function() {
    alert( $( '#mydiv' ).text() );
});
```

that will alert the contents of `#mydiv` as soon as the page finishes loading and is fully available.

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant `trigger()`

eg.

```
$( "#mydiv" ).on( "click", function() {
   alert( $( this ).text() );
});


$( "#mydiv" ).trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the jQuery [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) method

Any event handlers attached with .on() or one of its shortcut methods are triggered when the corresponding event occurs.

```
$( "#foo" ).on( "click", function() {
  alert( $( this ).text() );
});
$( "#foo" ).trigger( "click" );
```

In this example the foo click event is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    alert($("#mydiv").text())
})
```